# Android list adapter non-static method add(T) cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: android

I use this https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter to learn how to create a custom list adapter. However, I got the issue of "non-static method add(T)"

I try to add the data to the adapter by `Shop shop = new Shop (uid, name, address,email);
listadapter.add(shop);` <- but the error appears here.(This code in RegisterAccount Class)

**It is my listAdapter class**

```
public class shopListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Shop> {


public shopListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Shop> shops) {
    super(context, 0, shops);

}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Shop shop = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    }

    TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nameTV);
    TextView address = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.addressTV);

    name.setText(shop.getShopName());
    address.setText(shop.getAddress());

    return convertView;
}
}
```

**Model**

```
public Shop(String shopID, String name, String address, String email){
    this.shopID = shopID;
    this.name = name;
    this.address = address;
    this.email = email;
}
public void setShopID(String shopID) {
    this.shopID = shopID;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public void setAddress(String address) {
    this.address = address;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}
```

**Activity(in Fragment)**

```
 private void initAdapter(){

    ArrayList<Shop> arrayshop = new ArrayList<Shop>();

    shopListAdapter adapter = new shopListAdapter(getActivity(), arrayshop);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

}
```

**RegisterAccount**

```
  mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
  mProgress = new ProgressDialog(this);

  businessAccount = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("businessAcc");
 protected void startSetupAccount() {

    final String address = addressTF.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name = mNameField.getText().toString().trim();
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    final String email = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
    businessAccount.child(user_id).child("uid").setValue(user_id);
    businessAccount.child(user_id).child("username").setValue(name);
    businessAccount.child(user_id).child("address").setValue(address);
    businessAccount.child(user_id).child("email").setValue(email);
Shop shop = new Shop(uid,name,address,email);

            //shopListAdapter.add(shop);


                mProgress.dismiss();

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: custom adapter accepts type HairShop  whereas you are adding shop to it.

Comment: Post your RegisterAccount code...

Comment: Edited Sorry....

Comment: check my answer...

Comment: Please override function add in this adapter

Answer (score 0):

your adapter object is "adapter " and not "shopListAdapter" so instead of

```
shopListAdapter.add(shop);
```

do this

```
adapter.add(shop);
```

The first letter of your class should always be a Capital letter.
Read this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Comment: yes. you are calling add with class name but adapter's add method is not static so it has to be called with the object of adapter.In this case it is "adapter".

Comment: thx but after edit the answer I got this error when I try to add data in it why ?(java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.add(java.lang.Object)')

Comment: I have initAdapter but now it is not shown anything in listview ...... is that mean it already add?

Comment: it would be better if you show the complete code.Use http://pastebin.com/

Comment: It is here http://pastebin.com/G09RzMhv I have deleted unnecessary code Don't want to make it too long

Comment: your shop arraylist is null in Frag_SearchFragment...What i understood from your code : you are getting data(hair shop list) from firebase in activity and you are displaying the data in  Frag_SearchFragment.But you need to pass the data to your fragment too.

Comment: how can I pass the data in Fragment too?